# Java Regex verification

Tags: java, regex

i need to make a regex that matches either a or c on the first slot, "the char(0)"
but i only know how to use from A-Z

```
   string.matches(("^[A-C]{3}$")) //this includes B, i dont want this to happen
```

Can i add a string? or a char variable? insteas of the a and c? like

```
  "[+ char +]"
```

?

Comment: `^[ac]` is a regex that matches a or c as the first character of the string. But you don't need a regex to do this.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `-` in a character class expression, you allow the first character, the last character, and everything in between. Hence, `A-C` means `'A'`, `'B'`, or `'C'`. If you want either `'A'` or `'C'`, use `[AC]` instead:

```
string.matches(("^[AC]{3}$"))
```

> Can I add a `String` or a `char` variable?

Yes, if you obey the general rules of character class expressions:

- If you have a `-` or a `^` in your `String`, put them at the back
- If you have a `]` or `\` characters in your `String`, add an escape character in front of them.

Assuming that there are no special characters in your string, you can do

```
String str = "ac";
string.matches(("^[" + str + "]{3}$"))
```

Answer (score 1):

try `"^[AC]{3}$"`

The brackets match only a single character, so in this case they will match only A or C

Answer (score 1):

First you should have done some research in the internet: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html . This will give you very good tutorial on regex.

According to that link you should try:

```
string.matches(("^[AC]{3}$"))
```

Hope that helps